# Removing automatic filter using QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, query, filter, select

I opened a layer on QGIS 3.10.3 and got an automatic filter. I checked the Query builder, and nothing appears in the Query window. My colleague checked the attribute table on ArcMap. There is no filter.

How do I remove this filter in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: What format is the data stored in (gdb, gpkg, shp)? What way are you importing it into QGIS?

Comment: It is a shapefile. I just use the add layer option in QGIS.

Comment: Thanks. Right click on the layer in the Table of Contents and enable Show Feature Count, what does that say?

Comment: It says 613935.

Comment: This is very weird. If you use ctrl+A to select everything in the layer, how many are selected?

Comment: It says 593391. It is weird.